# Vistual host UBUNTU shows This site can’t be reached

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

I have configured virtual host on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, but it's not working.

Firstly created dir using:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/domain1.com/public_html
```

Then created index.html file inside it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to domain1.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! domain1.com home page!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

to avoid permission issues, I ran this command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/domain1.com
```

Then inside /etc/apache2/sites-available I have created a config file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain1.com.conf
```

And putted this code into it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain1.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain1.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then ran this command:

```
sudo a2ensite domain1.com
```

Then restarted apache using command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then Tested configuration:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

and got output as **Syntax OK**

but when I visit domain1.com in browser, getting `"This site can’t be reached"` error.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured Apache to special case any requests it recieves for `domain1.com`

You haven't:

- Registered domain1.com
- Configured a DNS server with an A record pointing domain1.com at the IP address that Apache is listening on

(Or done a local hack with something like a `hosts` file).